# Using LISTEN / NOTIFY in psql clients

Tags: postgresql, ipc, psql

I'm connected to same database server running in Docker container via `psql` client.

1. In client A I run `listen "virtual";`
2. In client B I run `notify "virtual";`

I would expect to see some kind of output in client A that it received asynchronous notification.

Can `psql` client be used this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notification is only retrieved from the server as a payload to a request. If the client does not send a request to the server, it will not see the notification.

In `psql` you can run an empty statement (only a `;`) to do that:

```
someuser=> ;
Asynchronous notification "virtual" received from server process with PID 11284.
someuser=>
```